# TypeError: Cannot instantiate typing.Optional

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have such a method:

`def select_unassigned_variable(self, variables: List[V]) -> Optional(V):`

I want this to return something of type `V` or `None` in some cases.
But I get such error:

`TypeError: Cannot instantiate typing.Optional`

What should I change?

Comment: I'd like to have this question reopened. It's the first result on Google when searching for the error message, and the second suggestion on SO when searching for the more common error "Cannot instantiate typing.Union". The error message isn't helpful, and seeing how parameters are usually used with parentheses, I'd say it's a valid question, absolutely reproducible, and not always caused by typos as the reason for closing says.

Comment: @jmkjaer how do I reopen it?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was for a moderator, since someone closed it. You cannot do anything right now :)

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question. AFAIK, the parenthesis syntax worked until Python 3.8. Python 3.9 requires them to be replaced by brackets. So, the question was NOT caused by a typo or a problem that can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use it with brackets instead of parentheses:

```py
def select_unassigned_variable(self, variables: List[V]) -> Optional[V]:
```

like you did with `List`.